# Svelte use scss, typescript for default

Tags: typescript, sass, svelte

I know that I can use Typescript, scss when I add lang, type with some svelte-preprocess config.

```
<script lang="ts"/>
<style type="scss"/>
```

But I'm too lazy to add this postfix everytime I made svelte file.
So I was looking for way to make scss, typescript as default langauge for style and script, but could not find one..

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a deprecated `defaults` option:

```js
sveltePreprocess({
  defaults: {
    script: "typescript",
    style: "scss",
  }
})
```

> Don't use "defaults" anymore, define the language being used explicitly instead

You can just leverage editor features like snippets or autocompletion to add the explicit annotations, e.g. [in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets):

```
// svelte.json
{
    "script": {
        "prefix": "script",
        "description": "Insert code for TypeScript script tag.",
        "body": [
            "<script lang=\"ts\">",
            "\t$0",
            "</script>",
        ]
    },
    // ...
}
```